# Cannot add any fields except selectbox and textbox in woocommerce_admin_billing_fields hook in woocommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, checkout, billing

I am using woocommerce plugin for my wordpress website.
I have added some fields(check box, radio button, etc..) in my billing form.
I want to add this fields in admin order edit billing address fields.
So I have used woocommerce_admin_billing_fields hook. In this hook, only select and text type is working. Others are not working.

Anyone has idea?

Comment: please include your code... it's hard to guess...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/1604009 refers this link to add custom fields to billing page.